# DB2+MQ, cannot create db2mq.tmp: Permission denied... but /tmp has my user

Tags: shell, docker, db2, ibm-mq, mq

I want create a trigger (in my database DB2) sending message to queue.
I use dockerfile to create build with IBM MQ, IBM DB2express-c and IBM IIB.
After I used command `enable_MQFunctions` (It creates DB2MQ tables+configuration) I got:

> sh: 1: cannot create db2mq.tmp: Permission denied

Using command `chown` I gave my user permission to **/tmp** and **var/tmp** but no possitive effect after, but mu user is listed (drwxrwxrwt) after I type `ls -ld tmp` command. 

Still my user can't `chmod 775 -R /tmp` -> Operation not permitted

Comment: I've got a few questions that might give some more information: What OS are you using?
Is this during the docker build or docker run?
Can you share your dockerfile?

Comment: I am using Docker on win10. In my container after succesfull built (with ubuntu 16.04 amd64) I log in, create some databases and want execute command enable_MQFunctions -n TEST -u db2inst1 -p pass. BTW, in linux I have two groups: db2 and mqm and I also add db2 user to mqm group. I am using db2 user, because only on that I have acces to command enable_MQFunctions. If I didn't adddb2 user to mqm group, I will not have acces to command creating default MQ

Comment: I used dockerfile from https://github.com/Davexa/IIB-MQ-DB2 + my slighty modify

Comment: @PetertheCruel is this resolved? Looks like a user error. If your description is correct, you have either not correctly added the additional group for db2inst1 (to mqm), or you have not logged-off db2inst1 and login again after that change. Additionally you can manually run amtsetup.sql per documentation instead of using enable_MQFunctions.

Comment: Hej @mao, I resolved problem in first post, but now I have very strange problem with command enable_MQFunctions. When I execute it, I get:  *** Error -- while connecting to TEST
      Make sure that user(db2inst1) and password(pass) are valid and that the DB2
      instance has started.
  *** enable_MQFunction finished with error                            ; dbname, user, pass are 100% ok. This is 2x more strange because beofre i could save db2mq.tmp file , anable_MQFunctions clearly see my database. I tried loggoff/login, db2stop/db2start....Still some connection issue...

Comment: @PetertheCruel If the symptom in the question is resolved then you should mark the question as answered, and open a new question for a different symptom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by adding forced permission *chmod -R 1777* (it's nooby way)